# Understanding Spring Application Construction

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I think that I'm missing something about Spring, and hopefully I'm not alone.

I've been trying to set up a Spring Boot application that will allow me to accomplish the following:

1. Create REST endpoints with Spring Web, in order to manipulate portions of a MySQL datastore
2. Secure these endpoints with Spring Security, in order to ensure that only specific users with specific privileges can modify portions of my datastore
3. Configure the entire application with very little external properties or XML files, since Spring Boot should, apparently, allow me to configure most of my application with the `@Bean` annotation

So far, I have only been able to set up the REST endpoints, but I have yet to figure out how to manipulate my datastore, mainly because I do not know how to connect to it (issue with number 3) or how to model it with the JPA.

Most of Spring's starter guides have been great for basic demonstration, but I cannot seem to complete any of the above 3 tasks on my own. I assume that other beginners have had this issue as well (perhaps because we don't know where to look), so I'm hoping that someone can provide definitive answers as to how one would go about completing these tasks.

Comment: Note that I am unsure as to whether or not these features come from all one Maven dependency, or if they come from multiple dependencies. These simply seem like common features to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your 3 feature sets are quite commonly used together, it is true, but not so commonly that there is a single Maven dependency that you can just magically add and they all just work. Spring Boot helps you by narrowing it down to 3 dependencies, if you want to go that route:

1. "spring-boot-starter-web" for your REST endpoints
2. "spring-boot-starter-security" for security
3. "spring-boot-starter-data-jpa" for Spring Data JPA

In addition to 3. you have to add a JDBC driver to your classpath appropriate for the database you are using (mysql, postgres, h2 etc.).

There are getting started guides covering each of these topics:

1. https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/
2. https://spring.io/guides/gs/securing-web/
3. https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-jpa/

There is also a longer tutorial with all your features (and some more): https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/bookmarks/

Comment: Excellent. And thank you for pointing me to the bookmarks tutorial -- it will be a huge help.